# Why doesn't an Ionic (v1) Android app work when there are multiple dependencies being injected in the main Angular module?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

## EDIT

I figured out what was going wrong. The folder which **some-other-module.js** was located in started with an underscore `_`, e.g., `_othermodule`. Seems like it was being ignored, although I'm not sure if it's ignored during building or during runtime. I removed the underscore and that fixed it.

---

## Original Post

I'm new to Ionic and I stumbled upon a problem which I can't seem to find solutions to.

When injecting multiple dependencies in the main Angular module, Ionic doesn't seem to work on the native Android app. It works on the browser, but when I run it on an Android phone, it just doesn't render properly.

**index.html** contains just the code for the [Todo app in the official Ionic v1 guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/starting.html).

**working app.js** (only `ionic` is injected)

```
//this code works

angular.module('app', [
  'ionic'
])
```

**not working app.js** (`some-other-module` is also injected with `ionic`)

```
//this code does not work

angular.module('app', [
  'ionic',
  'some-other-module'
])
```

**some-other-module.js** (empty for testing purposes, doesn't work even with a controller)

```
angular.module('some-other-module', [])
```

Comment: then the problem is in your `some-other-module.js`

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I see. Do you have any idea what's wrong with it? I've read other articles about structuring Ionic apps and they're similar to that of the usual Angular web applications.